# Why doesn't Angular provide a type for HttpClient's options paramter?

Tags: angular

Angular provides a helpful class called `HttpClient`. It's methods often take a parameter called `options`. Here's an example from `client.d.ts`:

```
    /**
     * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as an `ArrayBuffer` and returns the full event stream.
     *
     * @return an `Observable` of all `HttpEvent`s for the request, with a body type of `ArrayBuffer`.
     */
    get(url: string, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe: 'events';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'arraybuffer';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<HttpEvent<ArrayBuffer>>;
```

Why isn't an interface used for the `options` parameter? If I am wrapping this method, is there a good way to get some typesafety when passing the `options` parameter through to this method?

**Example**:

```
getUrl(url: string, options: >>>what-goes-here<<<): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpclient.get(url, options);
}
```

Obviously a trivial example, but we use methods like this to apply error handlers as well.

Comment: Because every method of HttpClient has more than 10 overloads that all take a different interface as options: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get. Wrapping HttpClient is generally not a good idea. If you want to apply common behavior, use an interceptor: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: If you put the first sentence as an answer, I'd accept that! As for not wrapping, sort of a digression, but we're wrapping HttpClient in a service that makes the method calls easier, as described here: https://angular.io/guide/http#why-write-a-service. We have some other helpers too as I mentioned for to capture errors. I'm not sure where you think an interceptor would be useful here -- handling errors? Seems like our wires might just be crossed a bit, but first sentence is what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Also, wait -- couldn't they have made all of those overloads with the slightly varied interfaces internal, and exposed a single method that accepts a parameter of some type they expose that could be delegated internally? It still seems possible to make the public interface more strongly typed. I get the feeling that I can be too tight-assed with typescript sometimes. I love it, but bits like this give me an itch that's hard to scratch.

Comment: No. The whole point of these overloads is to be public. What you pass as argument ise used by TypeScript to infer and check the return value of the method. For example, if you pass `observe: 'response'`, the **compiler** knows that the returned value is an Observable<HttpResponse<Something>> and not an Observable<Something>.

Comment: Regarding wrapping: the guide doesn't recommend wrapping HttpClient into a generic, reusable service. It recommends wrapping every http call you do from a component into a functional, dedicated service, that hides the specifics of that precise http call. So the controller precisely doesn't have to deal with HTTP. These options should be created by the service itself.

Comment: Regarding generic errors, yes, they typically are better handled by an interceptor, that always does the same generic thing, like displaying a generic error page or dialog box for example.